# SQL Server 2008 BULK INSERT causes more reads than writes. Why?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert, bulk-load

I've huge a table (a few billion rows) with a clustered index and two non-clustered indices.

A BULK INSERT operation produces 112000 reads and only 383 writes (duration 19948ms).

It's very confusing to me. Why do reads exceed writes? How can I reduce it?

update
query

```
insert bulk DenormalizedPrice4 ([DP_ID] BigInt, [DP_CountryID] Int, [DP_OperatorID] SmallInt, [DP_OperatorPriceID] BigInt, [DP_SpoID] Int, [DP_TourTypeID] Int, [DP_CheckinDate] Date, [DP_CurrencyID] SmallInt, [DP_Cost] Decimal(9,2), [DP_FirstCityID] Int, [DP_FirstHotelID] Int, [DP_FirstBuildingID] Int, [DP_FirstHotelGlobalStarID] Int, [DP_FirstHotelGlobalMealID] Int, [DP_FirstHotelAccommodationTypeID] Int, [DP_FirstHotelRoomCategoryID] Int, [DP_FirstHotelRoomTypeID] Int, [DP_Days] TinyInt, [DP_Nights] TinyInt, [DP_ChildrenCount] TinyInt, [DP_AdultsCount] TinyInt, [DP_TariffID] Int, [DP_DepartureCityID] Int, [DP_DateCreated] SmallDateTime, [DP_DateDenormalized] SmallDateTime, [DP_IsHide] Bit, [DP_FirstHotelAccommodationID] Int) with (CHECK_CONSTRAINTS)
```

No triggers & foreign keys
Cluster Index by DP_ID
and two non-unique indexes(with fillfactor=90%)

And one more thing DB stored on RAID50 with stripe size 256K

Comment: not enough detail to answer accurately...but an INSERT has to read to find the correct place to insert...

Comment: What kind of detail you need?

Comment: The actual SQL statement that you execute, and the table structure, would be helpful.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each row you insert, the database has to:

- Check contraints.  A unique constraint might require an index to be read into memory.  A foreign key constraint requires reading from another table.
- Find the pages which have to be updated (the clustered index, and any other indexes)
- Run any triggers that are defined on the table.

These activities might cause a lot of reads, and they have to be done for each row.  So it's perfectly normal to see hundreds of reads for a single row insert.  In fact, I'd take it as a healthy sign that the database is doing its work.